# How to bind a ListView with Directories and Files in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to bind All Directories and Files from C Drive in a ListView in C#

My Code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");

    FullDirList(di);
    ListView1.DataSource = lst;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}

ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

public void FullDirList(DirectoryInfo dir1)
{

    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir1.GetDirectories())
    {
        lst.Add(d);
    }

    foreach (FileInfo f in dir1.GetFiles() )
    {
        lst.Add(f);
    }
}
```

It gives the following error

> "An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'ListView1'"

Comment: Is this WPF, winforms ? Can you show the definition for ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write some aspx like this which includes an `ItemTemplate` for each list item. That's the error you are getting.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server">
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: of course it's giving you an error, i have only shown you the door, you are the one who has to walk through it :). You have to use Eval according to the property names you specify in your datasource, as my post says, i have only posted an example.

Comment: if you need more help, let me know