# An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'ListView1'. any one help me for this error

Tags: c#, .net

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into empoffice(empname,department,designation,empstatus,reportingto,grade,emplevel,doj) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')", con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        con.Close();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select *from empoffice",con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);

        ListView1.DataSource = ds;

        ListView1.DataBind();

     }
```

Comment: Is this WPF-related question? If so, show your XAML for `ListView1`.

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    
    </asp:ListView>

Comment: i just try to retrive the database values to listview databind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a ItemTemplate for your ListView, so it knows how to display your data when it loads it in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate.aspx

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/396_Getting_Started_with_the_ListView_Control.aspx

[How to bind a ListView with Directories and Files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934353/how-to-bind-a-listview-with-directories-and-files-in-c-sharp)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#CreatingTemplatesForTheListViewControl

Somewhere in these links you should find your answer. A simple Google search of the error you are getting will help you. Please try doing some research yourself before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>` pair of tags inside your ListView, so with something along the lines of below. I included a LayoutTemplate as well just for the heck of it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server">
         <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
         <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```